# Read with java HTML element value set by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to read a value from a HTML element that is set dynamically with javascript?

For example the element `<h1 id="title"></h1>` will change its value every 3 seconds and I want to read that value with Java.

The problem is that when I get the contents of that page using the classical example from here [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) all I get is just the element and not the element and the value in between the tags.

How can i read a value from a HTML element that is set dynamically with javascript?

Comment: You need a headless browser.

Comment: why you need to read the value using java ? what you want to do with that value in java ?

Comment: To make some sense of this question, post sufficient code to demonstrate what you are actually doing.

Comment: modify you JavaScript so when it changes it sends a new value to your backend using AJAX

Comment: if you are doing some Server Side code. you won't be able to grab the value of that HTML element unless you code something in Javascript to send a request to the server with the value it is changing.  am I close to what I think you are trying to do?

Comment: @AlexArt. you beat me to it...

Comment: @SLaks gave me the best answer. I search for headless browser in java and found [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html). That did the trick.
Thanks